# PiCam v2.1 - full res still capture buffering issue?

Tags: python, camera, raspberry-pi3

I am capturing stills with the newer 2.1 and want to use full resolution.  To now, I have been capturing at 2592, 1944 with no trouble.  When I set:
`camera.resolution = (3280, 2464)`
A successful capture is intermittent: sometimes multiple full res captures, sometimes a series of full res but 100% black, etc.

config note: my GPU allocation is 256M

My code is relatively simple:

```
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (3280, 2464)

#optimal
camera.brightness       = 40
camera.sharpness        = 0
camera.contrast         = 50
camera.exposure_mode    = "auto"
camera.awb_mode         = "incandescent"
camera.meter_mode       = "average"

camera.capture(root+fname)
camera.close()
```

I'm assuming it has to do with the data having enough time/bandwidth to flush to disk, but not sure how to tackle it.  Any ideas?  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I didn't 100% confirm, the problem seemed to be that the camera buffer didn't have enough time to flush to disk.  Since my subsequent operations (finding and recognizing text in the image) takes multiple seconds, having the camera slow down and take pictures only every x seconds instead of as fast as possible seemed to do the trick.